# How to display data using block code?

Tags: magento2, category, blocks

This is my code:

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/storecategories.phtml

```
<div>
<h3>
    <a href="">
        <?php
        $categoryId = 65;
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
            ->load($categoryId);
        $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        echo $category->getName();
        ?>
    </a>
</h3>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($childrenCategories as $childrenCategory) {
            echo "<li>" . "<a href=" . $childrenCategory->getUrl() . ">" .  $childrenCategory->getName() . "</a>" . "</li>";}
        ?>
</ul>
```

For now it echo out categories and children categories.

What I want to achieve is to type block code

```
{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\BlockName" category_id="49" template="Vendor_Module::storecategories.phtml"}}
```

into admin panel/Content/Pages/Home page/Content text area and call for categories and subcategories without using echo.

I suppose that I need to create Block file, but have no clue what code in it should look like.

Maybe I need controller as well and some changes in storecategories.phtml too?

Answer (score 0):

You not need to  create any controller but you have to  create block class.

So,you have to  create a module should have this command files:

```
app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/composer.json
app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/registration.php
app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/module.xml
```

then create a block file  `app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Block/BlockName` and write a function and return children category from this function to phtml.

**Block Class**

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Block

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class BlockName extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
     */
    private $categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    }

    const CATEGORYID =  65;

    public function getSubCatgories()
    {
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        $category->load(self::CATEGORYID);
        return $category;
    }
    /**
     * Return unique ID(s) for each object in system
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::CACHE_TAG, \Magento\Store\Model\Group::CACHE_TAG];
    }
}
```

**and phtml Code is**

```
<div>
<h3>
    <a href="">
        <?php

        $category =$this->getSubCatgories();
        if(category){
        $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        echo $category->getName();
        ?>
    </a>
</h3>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($childrenCategories as $childrenCategory) {
            echo "<li>" . "<a href=" . $childrenCategory->getUrl() . ">" .  $childrenCategory->getName() . "</a>" . "</li>";}
        ?>
</ul>
<?php  }?>
</div>
```